# Rotate view to extend content

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

The app of my bank is well designed. In portrait it displays the movements on my account and if the iPhone is in landscape mode (right or left) it displays a diagram with two axis. How can I do something like that? I have many views in my app and I need only the portrait mode but for one view, I need to display the content in landscape mode..

I tried this:

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: tried it and what did you get? You have to write code of your requirement in this method when `toInterfaceOrientation` is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` or `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

other macros defined in UIApplication.h:

```
UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation)

UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)

UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```